# How do I capture the audio output of the default audio device in C/C++ using pipewire like loopback capture in WASAPI in windows?

Tags: c++, c, linux, audio, pipewire

I am trying to capture the audio output of from the default sink of all the audio played by the system and perform fft on it. On the windows side I can easily do it using WASAPI. How Do I acheive this in linux?

For refence, the project is https://github.com/Dr-42/clwglava
In this I specifically want to translate the AudioCapture class to work on linux.

I tried looking into the source code of glava https://github.com/jarcode-foss/glava but it uses pulse. I also tried rummaging my way through the docs but didn't find out how to capture audio from a playback device rather than a cature device. I don't want to create loopback devices using alsa as it involves enabling kernel modules which is not user friendly.

Comment: C or C++? Don't tag both, they are distinct languages and there's no such thing as C/C++.

Comment: I would prefer C, but doing it in one of them makes doing this in the other one fairly trivial. Hence I tagged both

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to leave the library as is and instead install the middle man, something like `pipewire-pulse`. IIRC pipewire should work out with applications that expect pulse audio servers out of the box.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. I am currently using a solution based on pulse simple. But I was wondering if it could be done using pipewire directly.